# Is it better to say "I took a grade" or "I got a grade"?

Tags: phrases, active-vs-passive

I believe "I got a grade", or "I received a grade" is better, but I heard "I took a grade" which sounds strange to me because it sounds like it's an active process. Which of these forms are correct?

EDIT:
To be clear, I mean grade in the sense of a score that you get on a test, for example.

Comment: In the UK, people can say that they **took** a  degree or grade of degree. _After Ruskin [College] he took a BA at Oxford and a PhD at Essex [Universities]_  -- and --  _Dr. Oldfield took honours at Oxford in theology & law, and was called to the Bar. He later studied medicine at St. Bartholomew's Hospital_

Answer (score 1):

"I took a grade" is not a common expression.  When it does occur it is normally in the context "I took a grade 12 course".  In other words you "take a course" and that course may be described as "grade 12" (ie normally given to students in grade 12)

In the USA "grades" are the groups of students, usually of the same age. So one sometimes might say "I didn't take grade 12" to mean "I left high school before grade 12."  A "grade" is also the score that you got on an examination or for some assignment, or the final score you were given for a class for the entire semester or year.

In the UK "grades" are the scores (as letters or numbers) that students get on examinations.  In the UK you would indeed "get" a grade.

Comment: Note that in the US, a "grade" is also the score that you got on an examination or for some assignment, or the final score you were given for a class for the entire semester or year. Like you might say, "I got a 95% on this test" or "I got a B in math this year."